# array_shift() does not return an array

Tags: php

I am using php 4.4.9.

Here is the code:

```
$ipgenARRAY = explode('0',$ipgenPLAY); // every character will be an array value
$ipgenARRAYPLAY = array_shift($ipgenARRAY); // Chop off a character (0)
array_push($ipgenARRAYPLAY,"1"); // Add a one [first warning here]
$ipgenARRAY = $ipgenARRAYPLAY; // Save ^ change for the next time the loop is run
$ipgenARTEMP = implode(",",$ipgenARRAYPLAY); // Make the array into a string 
// with every array value split by a comma [second warning above]
$ipgenPLAY = str_replace(',','',$ipgenARTEMP); // remove all the commas
```

and here are the errors

```
Warning: array_push() [function.array-push]: First argument should be an array
Warning: implode() [function.implode]: Bad arguments
```

For whatever reason my array is not being accepted as an array

Comment: `I am using php 4.4.9` WOW!!!

Comment: If you're using PHP 4.4.9 because you're on a low-grade shared host, consider switching to a better one, such as hostgator or bluehost.

Comment: Agreed with @Walkerneo. Most shared hosting are now using PHP 5.x , which offers more modern functions by PHP.

Comment: I am using PHP 4.4.9 because I am coding for a wireless router and PHP5 is too clunky.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[`array_shift`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-shift.php) doesn't return an array, it returns the first value of the array passed in. The array passed in is modified.

Comment: Thanks code is now $ipgenARRAY = explode('0',$ipgenPLAY); //every one character is going to become another array value
array_shift($ipgenARRAY); //Chop off a characer (0)
array_push($ipgenARRAY,"1"); //Add a one
$ipgenARTEMP = implode(",",$ipgenARRAY); // Make the array into a string with every array value split by a comma
$ipgenPLAY = str_replace(',','',$ipgenARTEMP); //remove all the commas